# Access Oracle data on Sql server

Tags: sql-server, oracle, odbc, linked-server

I need to make a linked server on a **SQL Server** instance to get data from **Oracle**, but I'm finding it difficult.

I set up ODBC Oracle and the connection test succeeds, but when I try to create the linked server in SQL Server, the below message occurs.

The user of the Agent service and MSSQLSERVER is LocalSystem

> Can not initialize the data source object of OLE DB provider "MSDASQL"
>   for linked server "10.40.22.7". OLE DB provider "MSDASQL" for linked
>   server "10.40.22.7" returned message "The specified driver could not
>   be loaded due to system error 1114: A dynamic link library (DLL)
>   initialization routine failed. (Oracle in OraClient12Home1, G: \ app \
>   client \ adm_bds \ product \ 12.1.0 \ client_1 \ SQORA32.DLL). "
>   (Microsoft SQL Server, Error: 7303)

The file in the briefed folder exists.

Comment: check [this link](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/c596dd55-adce-4b6a-9805-e0c3b129d19c/sqora32-driver-could-not-be-loaded-system-error-1114-a-dynamic-link-library-dll-initialization?forum=w7itprogeneral)

Comment: it's not work :(

Comment: inspect the Windows event log for more details, what happened when initialization routine failed.

Comment: Also, make sure you have added to `PATH` environment variable all folders with Oracle system components. Probably MS SQL server is unable to find a dll dependency upon initialization process.

Answer (score 2):

`Oracle` version independent problem.

Restart the `MS SQL server` service after installing the `ODAC`.

`MS SQL service` must refresh the environment variables added after the installation of `ODAC`.

Answer (score 1):

Given that it was >1 year ago, this probably won't help Fabiano but may help others out there...

Encountered the same issue and it turned out to be the permission setting of SQORA32.DLL **as well as DLLs that SQORA32 depends on**. 
The account running MSSQLServer process needs to have read/execute permission on all relevant DLLs in that folder. (Use Task Manager to identify the account)

Add the account to security setting of the folder where SQORA32.DLL resides and let all files in the folder inherit the permission.

If you've changed the folder permission and you're still encountering the error message, ensure that the other files did not have permission inheritance disabled. My files weren't inheriting the folder permission (coz some genius disabled it) and despite giving SQORA32.DLL the correct permission setting, the same error message kept popping up and complaining about SQORA32.DLL. As it turns out, the error message was a red herring; it was the dependent DLLs that didn't have the correct permission setting.

~des

Answer (score 1):

The issue for me was that the folder that contains SQORA32.DLL was not in the PATH. After adding it to the system PATH and restarting sql server, the connection was established with no error.